# Retaining packages while upgrading

Tags: installation, upgrade, package-management

How can I retain installed package from a previous version of Ubuntu after upgrading that only the packages are retained and I don't have to download and install them again? or can I make a installer out of installed packages?

All I want to know that can I save my data plan .

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to a new version of Ubuntu, it is necessary to install newer versions of most installed applications. A substantial fraction of packages will need replacing, because either:

- The new Ubuntu release contains a newer version of the package, or
- The package version is similar, but because libraries in the base system have been updated upon which it depends, it has been rebuilt to work with them

I'm afraid the answer is that using the short term releases (12.10, 13.04, 13.10) does require a relatively large amount of bandwidth to keep updated. If you don't want to update on a 6-monthly cycle (with associated bandwidth usage), the LTS version (12.04 and probably 14.04 when available) allows you to keep the base system for 5 years from release.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all the bandwidth you can, start removing software you don't need/use. You can use `deborphan` to help you with the task of looking for orphan installed packages.

You can also consider downloading the ISO image and do a clean installation. Normally the upgrade manager will tell you the amount of data that will be downloaded. You should calculate if it would be easier to download just the ISO or to upgrade.

Last resort could be asking a friend without bandwidth cap to download the packages for you.